# YOCTO - A Issue: nativesdk-qtbase: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I m building my own Yocto distro based on i.MX6 using Yocto 4.14-sumo and QT5.12 recipe.
The embedded Yocto build works well.

But when I generate *sdk*, by launching :

`bitbake abl-image-qt5 -c populate_sdk`

I get the following error output on *nativesdk-qtbase* recipe :

```
ERROR: nativesdk-qtbase-5.12.0+gitAUTOINC+13ed06640c-r0 do_package: QA Issue: nativesdk-qtbase: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /opt/abl-imx-fb/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-ablsdk-linux/usr/share
  /opt/abl-imx-fb/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-ablsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake
  /opt/abl-imx-fb/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-ablsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake.d
  /opt/abl-imx-fb/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-ablsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake.d/OEQt5Toolchain.cmake
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
nativesdk-qtbase: 4 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: nativesdk-qtbase-5.12.0+gitAUTOINC+13ed06640c-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: nativesdk-qtbase-5.12.0+gitAUTOINC+13ed06640c-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/pierre/repo/claas/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-ablsdk-linux/nativesdk-qtbase/5.12.0+gitAUTOINC+13ed06640c-r0/temp/log.do_package.16550
ERROR: Task (/home/pierre/repo/claas/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/nativesdk-qtbase_git.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you used meta-qt5 from version warrior? The message says that the recipie installs the files using `do_install` but does not add them to `FILES` or any package.

You could add the following bbappend in your layer which should work

recipes-qt/qt5/nativesdk-qtbase_git.bbappend:

```
FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake.d/"
```

or ignore the problem

```
INSANE_SKIP_nativesdk-qtbase = "installed-vs-shipped"
```