# Yocto - how to add empty directory to file tree

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto

I'm building an embedded Yocto distro and want to add an empty directory `/home/root/mydir` but I get

```
ERROR: myrecipe-r0 do_package: QA Issue: usb-init: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
15:14:02    /home
15:14:02    /home/root
15:14:02    /home/root/mydir
15:14:02  Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
```

`/home/root` already exists on my target and my recipe contains

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d 
    install -d ${D}${base_prefix}/home/root/mydir

    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myinitscript.sh   ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/

}
```

which works ok for `init.d` but get the above error when I add `mydir`

I tried adding `FILES_${PN} += "${base_prefix}/home/root/mydir/*"` as suggested here, and it's still a no go.

[YOCTO - A Issue: nativesdk-qtbase: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666034/yocto-a-issue-nativesdk-qtbase-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-ship)

Is the issue caused by the fact I've not added any files in `mydir`? If so, what's the correct way to add empty directories in yocto?

Comment: `FILES_${PN} += "${base_prefix}/home/root/mydir` without the `/*` at the end? I would assume that you're saying please add all files in this dir but there are actually no files so it does not match the regexp. But if you're saying Yocto should add `mydir` to it, I think it could work.